# How to set body of HttpServletResponse using ktor client

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have spring boot controller

```
@PostMapping(path = ["/download"])
fun getFile(@RequestBody myObjectRq: myObjectRq, httpServletResponse: HttpServletResponse): CompletableFuture<HttpServletResponse> {
    return GlobalScope.async {
       val response = webService.getFile(myObjectRq)
       response?.let {
           httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", response.headers.get("Content-Type"))
           httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", response.headers.get("Content-Disposition"))
           httpServletResponse.writer.write(String(response.content.toByteArray()))
           httpServletResponse.writer.flush()
           httpServletResponse.status = response.status.value
       }
       httpServletResponse
   }.asCompletableFuture()
}
```

in which I use service which in turn uses ktor client to send post request to external server which should respond sending csv file. csv file content depends on values I send in `myObjectRq`.

Service:

```
suspend fun getFile(myObjectRq: myObjectRq): HttpResponse {
    val response = ktorClient.post<HttpResponse> {
        accept(ContentType.Application.OctetStream)
        url(externalWebServerUrl)
        body = myObjectRq
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    }
    log.info(String(response.content.toByteArray()))
    response
}
```

Headers in response are properly set, also `log.info(String(response.content.toByteArray()))` in the method prints out the content of received file, but I can't set it as a body of `HttpServletResponse`. I keep getting `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`.

Also I get `Inappropriate blocking method call` for `httpServletResponse.writer` which kind of breaks async qualities of ktor client.
What do I do wrong? How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

So, I think SpringBoot is confused with your return type. It is trying to find a way to serialize your return `CompletableFuture<HttpServletResponse>` into the body of the HTTP response but failing. I believe you can achieve the same result by changing your implementation as follows:

```
@PostMapping(path = ["/download"])
fun getFile(@RequestBody myObjectRq: myObjectRq, httpServletResponse: HttpServletResponse): CompletableFuture<Void> {
    return GlobalScope.async {
       val response = webService.getFile(myObjectRq)
       response?.let {
           httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", response.headers.get("Content-Type"))
           httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", response.headers.get("Content-Disposition"))
           httpServletResponse.writer.write(String(response.content.toByteArray()))
           httpServletResponse.writer.flush()
           httpServletResponse.status = response.status.value
       }
       null
   }.asCompletableFuture()
}
```

Comment: I actually tried to use Unit and this was kinda ok, as body was printed out in the response but the spring error still remained.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve this using `CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ByteArray>>` as return type and setting body of the response this way:
 `ResponseEntity.ok().body(response.content.toByteArray())`
This also removed `Inappropriate blocking method call` warnings.